# Convert Month into weeks in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am looking to breakdown a Month into weeks(starting Monday) in MySQL.

For example,

```
 Sept 3 - 9th 

 Sept 10 - 16th
```

How to achieve this using MySql?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will produce the results you want. It generates a table of possible week numbers in the month (0 to 4) using a `UNION`, and then it adds those week numbers to the computation of the first Monday of the month (stored in the variable @firstday which is JOINed to the table of week numbers).

```
SELECT @firstday + INTERVAL w WEEK AS start, @firstday + INTERVAL w WEEK + INTERVAL 6 DAY AS end 
FROM (SELECT 0 AS w UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) weeks
JOIN (SELECT @firstday := FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(CURDATE())-DAY(CURDATE())+1) +
                          (7 - WEEKDAY(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(CURDATE())-DAY(CURDATE())+1))) % 7) f
HAVING end <= LAST_DAY(@firstday)
```

Output:

```
start       end     
2018-09-03  2018-09-09
2018-09-10  2018-09-16
2018-09-17  2018-09-23
2018-09-24  2018-09-30
```

To run the query for any given month, replace `CURDATE()` in the computation of `@firstday` (4 places) with a date in the month you are interested in e.g.

```
SELECT @firstday + INTERVAL w WEEK AS start, @firstday + INTERVAL w WEEK + INTERVAL 6 DAY AS end 
FROM (SELECT 0 AS w UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) weeks
JOIN (SELECT @firstday := FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS('2018-01-20')-DAY('2018-01-20')+1) +
                          (7 - WEEKDAY(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS('2018-01-20')-DAY('2018-01-20')+1))) % 7) f
HAVING end <= LAST_DAY(@firstday)
```

Output:

```
start       end     
2018-01-01  2018-01-07
2018-01-08  2018-01-14
2018-01-15  2018-01-21
2018-01-22  2018-01-28
```

If you have the flexibility of setting variables, you can clean up the query like so:

```
SET @day = '2018-01-20';
SET @firstday := FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(@day)-DAY(@day)+1) + (7 - WEEKDAY(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(@day)-DAY(@day)+1))) % 7;
SELECT @firstday + INTERVAL w WEEK AS start, @firstday + INTERVAL w WEEK + INTERVAL 6 DAY AS end 
FROM (SELECT 0 AS w UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) weeks
HAVING end <= LAST_DAY(@firstday)
```

Comment: This should help. Also I would like to breakdown a value for a month into value for a week.                                                                                                        For example, if the values for Sept, 2018 was 16 I would want to break it down into the corresponding week values. For week of Sept 1-2, since it makes up 2 days for Sept -> (2 * 16)/30; for week of Sept 3 - 9 -> (7*16)/30.                      
 Also for week of Sept 30 - Oct 6( say value for Oct = 20) , the calculation would be : (1 * 16)/30 + (6*20)/31 . How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function week(date) - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week